# Where I can find script in project files in asp.net webAPI app?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webapi

I create simple asp.net WEB API application. When I run it, i see this view :
[image]

When I try to inspect code i see that in  there are some scripts of course, but i cant find
this scripts in my file in Visual Studio (project was generated automatically)...
Can someone tells me why?

Source:
{[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S30IF.png)

Comment: can you show the source you used?

Comment: I added it to my post

Comment: that was nt what i meant, the soiurce of the project

Comment: I have just create WEB Api project in Visual Studio Code

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-daily-Weather-Forecast-using-Weather-API-in-ASPNet.aspx  this here gets its data from openweather maybe that helps you

Comment: I mean, that in automatic project there are no any files like HTML or Razor, so why page show something like navBar?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It is located in the weather forecast controller

There you find

```
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
  var rng = new Random();
  return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
  {
    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
    TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
    Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
  })
  .ToArray();
}
```

As you can see it creates 5 "WeatherForecast" with random numbers

The diplay part happens here.

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
  });
```

For the rest pkease check the documentation